# Date Range in Where clause

Tags: ssas

I have ssas DB with two cubes, they share the date dimension.
My query shows users on the dimension and visit as a measure. In the where clause I have range of dates.
I have this strange behavior that after a FULL cube process I don't see any data when applying the range. I'm sure that I have data for the range because when I filter each day desperately I can see data.
Another weird scenario is that if the date is on the dimension I can see data.
The thing that solve it is when process DATA the cubes.
This my query:

```
select non empty [Users].[User].[User] columns, 
  {[Measures].[Visits]} on rows 
  from [System Visit] where 
     ([Dim_Date].[Georgian Calendar].[Date ID].&[20150125]:[Dim_Date].[Georgian Calendar].[Date ID].&[20150202])
```

Any thought what can be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: 1) Do you have a data exactly on border members `[20150125]` and `[20150202]` too? 2) Are we talking about only one cube `[System Visit]` during `process full` and `query` operations, but `process data` is applied for both cubes? 3) Are there some calculated members, which use `LookupCube` function and retrieve data from another cube?

Comment: 1. Sometimes I do have data on the borders and sometimes no, same result either way.(Most of the times I do). 2. I have to cubes in that DB, I do process Full on the DB, so both cubes bring processed. 3. The measure is very straight forward (mapped to a column in the DB).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the borders defined then your filter will work like NULL:a, b:NULL, or NULL:NULL depending on availability of border in the cube.

In this case, I would suggest all possible dates into your [Dim_Date].[Date ID] attribute.

Comment: I have all dates in the cube,and most of the time I have actual fact data for them. The query is always generated with  from to and never with null. Also , when I put only one date I see data, just with the range I have the issue.

Comment: in some cases, using multiselect can cause trouble with cube calculations. For example, currentmember function cannot be used in case of multi selects. In such cases, existing function should be used instead of currentmember

Comment: I don'y have any multiselect in the query...It's very simple query and the weird  thing is that when I do process data it fix it.

Comment: Actually when you have a range of members of one attribute in the where clause, it is named as multi-select. For example things like a:b is a multi-select. But loading cube should not fix such an issue.